# Untracked files even after git add -a

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a server in which I have made some modifications and used git add -a and changed git remote repo from server and pushed the code to it but the changed files are not present on git repo.

If i pull down the code to my local machine from the new repo also the changes are not visible.

What can i do in at this scenario?

Comment: Might be a simple remark but are you on the same branch?

Comment: Only one branch

Comment: I assume you did a `git commit` after `git add` and before `git push`? If not, you have to commit first. `git add` will add the files only to the index, but it doesn't commit.

Comment: I have done in the same way only git commit after git add and before git push

Comment: Are you looking at the right branch in the remote ? May be you are looking into wrong branch at remote

Comment: Are you sure of the server address ?  Have you tried `git add -A` instead ? (You can of course check what you added with `git status`)

Comment: Is this has something to do with digital ocean?  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-connect-to-my-do-git-repo-with-git-push-command#